# How long can we preserve yogurt using a refrigerator?

Tags: milk, yogurt, frozen-yogurt

How long can we keep yogurt in the refrigerator and still consume it?

Comment: Shop bought, or home made? Shop bought yoghurt tends to be stamped with a "use by" date a few weeks after the purchase date, and I've generally found it's OK to eat for about a month after that date. (For a plain, unflavoured yoghurt, probably even longer.)

Answer (score 3):

This link should help you. It should be ok at least a week or two past the use by date.

http://www.eatbydate.com/dairy/yogurt-shelf-life-expiration-date/